# Updating my App - Apple App Store and Google Play Store

Tags: android, ios, cordova

The company that I work for wants me to add a few features to their app. It is built using ionic cordova. I have added all the features in the development code and now I need to push the code to production. I don't exactly know how to do it. Does Apple recheck my new releases (can Apple reject my updates?). How long does it the app store and the play store to update my app?

Comment: Questions about app distribution channels and their policies is considered to be [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic). You might consider trying [other Android developer support sites](http://www.andglobe.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The average review time for [the Apple app store is 2 days](http://appreviewtimes.com/).
The average review time for [the Google Play store is 6-12 hours](http://guarana.helpscoutdocs.com/article/53-android-google-play-average-review-time).

Both reserve the right to reject the new version of the app but its unlikely that they will, unless you breach [Google](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy/) or [Apples](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/rejections/) app policies.

To do the update follow the App update steps in the respective platforms' documentation. Here is [Google's](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en) and here is [Apple's](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html). Good luck!